# xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError on parsing XML

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse XML with Python but not getting very far. I think it's due to wrong XML tree this API returns.

So this is what is returned by the GET request:

```
<codigo>3</codigo><valor></valor><operador>Dummy</operador>
```

The GET request goes here:

```
http://69.36.9.147:8090/clientes/SMS_API_OUT.jsp?codigo=ABCDEFGH&cliente=XX
```

This is the Python code I am using without any luck:

```
import urllib
from xml.dom import minidom

url = urllib.urlopen('http://69.36.9.147:8090/clientes/SMS_API_OUT.jsp?codigo=ABCDEFGH&cliente=XX')
xml = minidom.parse(url)
code = doc.getElementsByTagName('codigo')

print code[0].data
```

And this is the response I get:

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: junk after document element: line 1, column 18
```

What I need to do is retrieve the value inside the `<codigo>` element and place it in a variable (same for the others).

Comment: Shouldn't that be "code = xml.getElementsByTagName..."?

Comment: Whoops, yeh nevertheless the script fails when it comes to parsing. Like Greg pointed out because of an invalid XML, however I can't control the content of the XML...

Comment: i'm not really that up on minidom yet, but I can find no where in the documentation that says that a node element has a data variable. the comment objects have that, but that's not a comment. shouldn't you be using nodeValue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main problem here is that the XML code being returned by that service doesn't include a root node, which is invalid. I fixed this by simply wrapping the output in a `<root>` node.

```
import urllib
from xml.etree import ElementTree

url = 'http://69.36.9.147:8090/clientes/SMS_API_OUT.jsp?codigo=ABCDEFGH&cliente=XX'
xmldata = '<root>' + urllib.urlopen(url).read() + '</root>'
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xmldata)
codigo = tree.find('codigo').text

print codigo
```

You can use whatever parser you wish, but here I used ElementTree to get the value.

Comment: For a Python 3 version of this answer, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75887074/2745495

Answer (score 4):

An XML document consists of *one* top level document element, and then multiple subelements. Your XML fragment contains multiple top level elements, which is not permitted by the XML standard.

Try returning something like:

```
<result><codigo>3</codigo><valor></valor><operador>Dummy</operador></result>
```

I have wrapped the entire response in a `<result>` tag.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have control over the XML file. If you look at the response you get when visiting the URL I posted on top, that is all I have to work with. If not possible with XML how could I do it?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: In that case, take the response you get from the URL using `url.read()`, put an appropriate tag such as `<result>` and `</result>` around it, *then* pass it to the `minidom.parseString()` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib.request
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with urllib.request.urlopen("<your URL>") as url:
    xmldata = '<root>' + str(url.read()) + '</root>'
    tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xmldata)
    codigo = tree.find('codigo').text
```

For an explanation, see the original Python 2 version of this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1140753/2745495

Comment: The solution presented here (wrapping inside <root>) is mostly a copy of the accepted answer. You could have just commented or submitted an edit to suggest using a context manager.

Comment: urllib.urlopen(url) is not working in Python 3, and also I can not add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the xml data doesn't come as expected in the format.
In my case, it happened because the api's token expired and it was giving xml data that cannot be parsed.

So I suggest, check your data and see if the data is in correct format or not.