# How can I get specific elements from XML data?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have some code to retrieve XML data:

```
import cStringIO
import pycurl
from xml.etree import ElementTree

_API_KEY = 'my api key'
_ima = '/the/path/to/a/image'

sock = cStringIO.StringIO()

upl = pycurl.Curl()

values = [
            ("key", _API_KEY),
            ("image", (upl.FORM_FILE, _ima))]

upl.setopt(upl.URL, "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.xml")
upl.setopt(upl.HTTPPOST, values)
upl.setopt(upl.WRITEFUNCTION, sock.write)
upl.perform()
upl.close()
xmldata = sock.getvalue()
#print xmldata
sock.close()
```

The resulting data looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<upload><image><name></name><title></title><caption></caption><hash>dxPGi</hash><deletehash>kj2XOt4DC13juUW</deletehash><datetime>2011-06-10 02:59:26</datetime><type>image/png</type><animated>false</animated><width>1024</width><height>768</height><size>172863</size><views>0</views><bandwidth>0</bandwidth></image><links><original>https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxPGi.png</original><imgur_page>http://imgur.com/dxPGi</imgur_page><delete_page>http://imgur.com/delete/kj2XOt4DC13juUW</delete_page><small_square>https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxPGis.jpg</small_square><large_thumbnail>https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxPGil.jpg</large_thumbnail></links></upload>
```

Now, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140672/parsing-xml/1140753#1140753), I'm trying to get some specific values from the data.

This is my attempt:

```
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xmldata)
url = tree.findtext('original')
webpage = tree.findtext('imgur_page')
delpage = tree.findtext('delete_page')

print 'Url: ' + str(url)
print 'Pagina: ' + str(webpage)
print 'Link de borrado: ' + str(delpage)
```

I get an `AttributeError` if I try to add the `.text` access:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 27, in <module>
    url = tree.find('original').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I couldn't find anything in Python's help for `ElementTree` about this attribute. How can I get only the text, not the object?

I found some info about getting a text string [here](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findtext); but when I try it I get a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 34, in <module>
    print 'Url: ' + url
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

If I try to print `'Url: ' + str(url)` instead, there is no error, but the result shows as `None`.

How can I get the url, webpage`and`delete_page` data from this XML?

Comment: it's a path issue, you can't just get original element directly with tree.find because original element is a child of image element which is a child of upload, try to use tree.findall('.//original')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `find()` call is trying to find an immediate child of the top of the tree with a tag named `original`, not a tag at any lower level than that. Use:

```
url = tree.find('.//original').text
```

if you want to find all elements in the tree with the tag named `original`. The pattern matching rules for ElementTree's `find()` method are laid out in a table on this page: http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm

For `//` matching it says:

> Selects all subelements, on all levels beneath the current element (search the entire subtree). For example, “.//egg” selects all “egg” elements in the entire tree.

Edit: here is some test code for you, it use the XML sample string you posted I just ran it through XML Tidy in TextMate to make it legible:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
xmldata = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<upload>
    <image>
        <name/>
        <title/>
        <caption/>
        <hash>dxPGi</hash>
        <deletehash>kj2XOt4DC13juUW</deletehash>
        <datetime>2011-06-10 02:59:26</datetime>
        <type>image/png</type>
        <animated>false</animated>
        <width>1024</width>
        <height>768</height>
        <size>172863</size>
        <views>0</views>
        <bandwidth>0</bandwidth>
</image>
<links>
    <original>https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxPGi.png</original>
    <imgur_page>http://imgur.com/dxPGi</imgur_page>
    <delete_page>http://imgur.com/delete/kj2XOt4DC13juUW</delete_page>
    <small_square>https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxPGis.jpg</small_square>
    <large_thumbnail>https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxPGil.jpg</large_thumbnail>
</links>
</upload>'''
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xmldata)
print tree.find('.//original').text
```

On my machine (OS X running python 2.6.1) that produces:

```
Ian-Cs-MacBook-Pro:tmp ian$ python test.py 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxPGi.png
```